# rspec fails basic tests for a table

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I created two very similar tables. One of them is called performer and the other one is performance. Performer only contains a name:string. While Performance contains file_name:string, date:date and location:string. I have very similar rspec files for both of them and the Performer test passes with no issues however the performance fails the test of all 3 attributes. When i enter sandbox and test the attributes with

`performance = Performance.new 
performance.respond_to?(:file_name)` it returns true.

Yet in rspec it fails. 
Here are the failures.

```
1) Performance
     Failure/Error: it { should respond_to(:date) }
       expected Performance(id: integer, file_name: string, date: date, location
: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) to respond to :date
     # ./spec/models/performance_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (requir
ed)>'

  2) Performance
     Failure/Error: it { should respond_to(:file_name) }
       expected Performance(id: integer, file_name: string, date: date, location
: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) to respond to :file_name
     # ./spec/models/performance_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (require
d)>'

  3) Performance
     Failure/Error: it { should respond_to(:location) }
       expected Performance(id: integer, file_name: string, date: date, location
: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) to respond to :location
     # ./spec/models/performance_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (requir
ed)>'
```

here is my rspec file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Performance do
   before { @performance = Performance.new(file_name: "Example Performece", 
                                               date: DateTime.parse("2011-06-02T23:59:59+05:30").to_date,
                                           location: "lame house", ) }
    subject { Performance }

    it { should respond_to(:file_name) }
    it { should respond_to(:date) }
    it { should respond_to(:location) }
end
```

My performer file is extremely similar, Is the date attribute somehow messing this thing up? I tried creating an empty performance with Performance.new but it didnt fix the problem so i dont know whats going on.

If you want to see my files comment below and ill post them here. Im by the computer so i should be quick to respond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use one-liner syntax like:

```
it { should have_something }
```

It is exactly like you wrote

```
it 'should have something' do
  subject.should have_something
end
```

In your code you have declared your subject to be *the class* `Performance`:

> ```
> subject { Performance }
> ```

This means that your tests are actually:

```
it 'should respond to file_name' do
  Performance.should respond_to(:file_name)
end
```

Which, of course, it doesn't.

When you set the subject to `@performance`

```
subject { @performance }
```

the test becomes:

```
it 'should respond to file_name' do
  @performance.should respond_to(:file_name)
end
```

which should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

subject should be

```
subject { Performance.new(file_name: "Example Performece", date: DateTime.parse("2011-06-02T23:59:59+05:30").to_date, location: "lame house", ) }
```

that's all

Comment: thanks it works now. However how is it that my other file for performer works with the following code `before { @performer = Performer.new(name: "Example Performer" ) }
 subject { Performer }
 
 it { should respond_to(:name) }` but not in the performance one?

Comment: performance started working when i added the @ symbol in the subject { @performance } This behavior is really confusing for me. I guess i leave the question open until somebody explains to me whats going on. If noone will in a while i will accept your answer since it did fix my problem

Comment: `name` does work, because the class has a property `name`! `String.name # => "String"`

Comment: so, do you actually understand the difference between `@performance` and `Performance`? if not, you might take a step back and understand the language and the framework before writing tests.